# Docker - can we manage auth-system, user-session and cookies with an app running inside a container using Docker Community Edition?

Tags: docker

I'm working with Docker and I have seen that Docker Enterprise Edition provide some feature for using cookies. So I'm wondering as the title says if we can manage auth-system, user-session, and cookies with an app running inside a container using Docker Community Edition?

If someone has any hint, would be great,

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You can run an Web application with arbitrary ordinary HTTP cookie management on Docker CE fine.  Is there specific functionality you're aiming for that Docker CE doesn't provide?

Comment: thanks David, I have seen that : https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/interlock/usage/sessions/ and I didn't seen the sticky session feature on Docker CE hence I wondered if that existed so, I search for cookies simply, okay good if it works with Docker CE I will test it